# Passing Range Variable into formula in Excel Macro

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Im trying to use variables in macro formulas to avoid selecting cells, however i keep getting an error.

Here is a simplification of what im trying to do:

```
    Dim myRange as Range
    Dim formulaCell as Range

    Set myRange = [a1:a10]
    formulaCell.Formula = "=sum(myRange)"
```

However i keep getting:

```
"application-defined or object defined error"
```

I have tried using:

```
formulaCell.Formula = "=sum(" & myRange & ")"
```

but then i get:

```
Type mismatch
```

Also tried:

```
formulaCell.Formula = "=sum(" & Range(myRange) & ")"
```

to no avail

Im sure the answer is very basic but cannot work out what i am doing wrong. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you must set `formulaCell` to refer to a Range. Then use next string instead of yours

```
formulaCell.Formula = "=sum(" & myRange.Address & ")"
```