# Passing parameter to a formula cell in evaluate function

Tags: excel, vba

I am learning VBA to automate my day to day xl tasks and stuck with below issue.

I am trying to pass each cell value from the Range A2:A5 as a parameter into the formula placed in the cell E3 and execute it using 'Application.Evaluate(range("E3").value)' through VBA. Finally paste that result to the Range C2:C5.

[image: Example pic]

**What I have done so far:**

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811719/passing-range-variable-into-formula-in-excel-macro) gave some insight on how to pass arguments into an evaluate function. But I don't want to bring (hard code) my formula into the script as that formula could change over the time.

I am trying to do something like this

```
Public Sub test()
'defined variable

for i = 2 to 5
  var = range("A" & i).value
  '=sum(var+10) is in Range("E3")
  range("C" & i).value = Application.Evaluate(Range("E3").value)
next
End Sub
```

I am looking for some *pointers* on how to tackle it.

P.S. The formula in attached snap is only an example. I have several scientific expressions which I am picking for further calculations in place of *formula* based on a dropdown list value.

Comment: That won't work as the worksheet doesn't know what `var` is. Why not just evaluate the expression in VBA?

Comment: Sorry, I missed to include in my question that I have several (scientific) expression which I am picking for further calculations based on a dropdown list value. And all expressions have **that 'var'** parameter in common.
So instead of including each expression in script, trying to get through this approach.

Comment: It's not much more onerous to write `Application.Evaluate("=sum(" & var & "+10)")` is it?

Comment: I agree, it's not. But in the future when the `=sum` expression changes to something else again I'll have to make changes to the code. I am feeling that it (expression change) is easier to handle changes at cell level.

Comment: `range("C" & i).value = Application.Evaluate(Replace(Range("E3").value,"var",range("A" & i).value))`

Comment: Thank you @ScottCraner. It's an interesting approach  to use `replace`, I didn't think of it in first place.
I'll give it a try and update again here.

Comment: That line of code is working exactly as I wanted. Thanks again @ScottCraner . Kindly guide me how to select the comment as _accepted answer_.